# Why does merely evaluating a subtraction from a UInt crash in Swift?

Tags: swift

I don't know the rules for when a math operation "upgrades" the result to the numeric type of one of the operands (for example, when one is an int and the other a float), but this surprised me:

```
@IBAction func LUTButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    guard let buttonIndex: Int = m_LUTButtons.index(of: sender) else {return}

    // device.selectedLUTSlot is a UInt32
    if buttonIndex == device.selectedLUTSlot - 1    // THIS CRASHES WHEN device.selectedLUTSlot == 0.
    {
        return
    }
```

I'm not trying to assign the negative number to the UInt32, and I'm comparing the result of the subtraction to a signed type.  So this runtime crash strikes me as non-intuitive and error-prone.  What's the rationale here?

Comment: You’re saying that that code compiles?? It shouldn’t.

Comment: Yep, and runs. I only discovered the bug when I tapped a button before that UInt32 was set non-zero. I would ask why it shouldn't compile, but... that's what this post is about.

Comment: Yep, I can reproduce.

Comment: OK, so "heterogeneous comparisons" are a thing. Working on it...

Comment: Yes, this has been legal since Swift 4. I knew this but then I forgot it. And I probably didn't understand how it worked. Thanks for making me think about it.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the question, a simple solution would be `buttonIndex + 1 == device.selectedLUTSlot`

Comment: The real solution (which I used) is to make sure device.selectedLUTSlot != 0.

Comment: @Clashsoft Oh, there are lots of ways to make sure we don't form an illegal UInt32 by subtraction. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint32/2885137-subtractingreportingoverflow is one of many (and is a better solution). But as you say, that _isn't_ the question. The question is why we can do this _at all_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to be clear about is that the entire thing on the right side of the comparison is a UInt32:

```
... == device.selectedLUTSlot - 1
```

`device.selectedLUTSlot` is a UInt32, so `1` is a UInt32 because *literals* (unlike variables) are automatically coerced to match their fellow operands. Therefore their difference is a UInt32, and if the code ever runs with `device.selectedLUTSlot` set to `0`, we will crash.

Okay. But why is the code permitted to compile and run, when the thing on the *left* side of the comparison is an Int? What happened to Swift's strict numeric typing?

Well, there's a BinaryInteger generic protocol, to which every integer type conforms:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger

And every integer type has an `==` operator like this:

```
public static func == <Other>(lhs: Int, rhs: Other) -> Bool 
    where Other : BinaryInteger
```

Thanks to that, you can compare two integers of different types:

```
/// You can use relational operators, such as the less-than and equal-to
/// operators (`<` and `==`), to compare instances of different binary integer
/// types. The following example compares instances of the `Int`, `UInt`, and
/// `UInt8` types:
///
///     let x: Int = -23
///     let y: UInt = 1_000
///     let z: UInt8 = 23
///
///     if x < y {
///         print("\(x) is less than \(y).")
///     }
///     // Prints "-23 is less than 1000."
///
///     if z > x {
///         print("\(z) is greater than \(x).")
///     }
///     // Prints "23 is greater than -23."
```

Thus you can compare an Int with a UInt32. Therefore your code compiles. Therefore your code runs. But on the right side of the equation, you are forming a UInt32 less than 0, as we already established. Therefore your code crashes.

Comment: Thanks. Why is it forming a UInt32 instead of promoting the result to a signed type (unless there's no signed int bigger than UInt32)?

Comment: @Oscar Because `device.selectedLUTSlot` is a UInt32 and `1` is a UInt32 so their difference is a UInt32. You cannot combine two different integer types using an arithmetic operator. The arithmetic operation is simply performed, which is what you requested be done. If you didn't want that, you shouldn't have done it. There are lots of ways to check whether an operation _would_ over/underflow without actually performing it.

Comment: That's really the answer to the question. "1" can be interpreted as a UInt32 so there is no obvious promotion to do. I moved that up into the answer, since I think it's an important observation.

Comment: @Oscar I edited your edit to bring that point even further forward in the answer (right at the top). I didn't realize you didn't know about automatic coercion of numeric literals.